# Some misspelled SSH hosts are resolved to 127.0.0.1 equivalent

Tags: ssh, fedora, dns

I have a Fedora 25 machine. Sometimes I misspell a hostname for SSH. Then I do `ssh examle.com`. For some reason, I then get connected to my machine (`localhost`) via SSH. I notice this because if there are `SSH_` variables in the environment, my shell prompt shows that.

Right now at home, I get a clean hostname resolution error. What could be the cause of this on occasion? Some local DNS server just resolving everything it does not know to `127.0.0.1`?

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no

host juqueen
hostname juqueen.fz-juelich.de
user hbn28e
controlpath ~/.ssh/controlmasters/%r@%h:%p
controlmaster auto
controlpersist 15m


host judac
hostname judac.fz-juelich.de
user hbn28e
controlpath ~/.ssh/controlmasters/%r@%h:%p
controlmaster auto
controlpersist 15m

host martin-ueding.de
hostname martin-ueding.de
user ssh-444717-mu
StrictHostKeyChecking yes

host hiskp
hostname plato.itkp.uni-bonn.de                                                                                        
user ueding                                                                                                            

host chaos                                                                                                             
hostname chaos.stw-bonn.de                                                                                             
user mu                                                                                                                

host gateway.cb.uni-bonn.de                                                                                            
ForwardAgent yes                                                                                                       
hostname gateway.cb.uni-bonn.de                                                                                        
user ueding                                                                                                            
checkhostip yes                                                                                                        
controlpath ~/.ssh/controlmasters/%r@%h:%p                                                                             
controlmaster auto                                                                                                     
controlpersist 15m                                                                                                     

host qbig                                                                                                              
ForwardAgent yes                                                                                                       
#hostname gateway.cb.uni-bonn.de                                                                                       
ProxyCommand ssh gateway.cb.uni-bonn.de "nc qbig %p"                                                                   
user ueding                                                                                                            
checkhostip yes                                                                                                        
controlpath ~/.ssh/controlmasters/%r@%h:%p                                                                             
controlmaster auto                                                                                                     
controlpersist 15m                                                                                                     

host gsp.fz-juelich.de                                                                                                 
hostname gsp.fz-juelich.de                                                                                             
identityfile ~/.ssh/id_gsp_owncloud                                                                                    

host martin-welsh                                                                                                      
hostname martin-welsh.fritz.box                                                                                        

host martin-shire                                                                                                      
hostname martin-shire.fritz.box                                                                                        

host martin-friese
hostname martin-friese.fritz.box
#hostname 192.168.188.71

host root@martin-welsh
user root
hostname martin-welsh.local

host martin-criollo
hostname 192.168.188.21
user shell
port 2222

host martin-falabella
hostname martin-falabella.fritz.box
port 2222

host cip
hostname cip-pool.physik.uni-bonn.de
user s6mauedi
```

---

At home, I have an AVM FRITZ!Box router. That does some DNS magic and lets you resolve names in the local network. So I can do `ssh martin-friese.fritz.box` from another computer and get a connection to the laptop. This nicely works without any Avahi/Zeroconf/Bonjour stuff and therefore also supports Windows and Android right away. The address http://fritz.box gets resolved to the router's web interface (`192.168.???.1`).

At the university, my computer still has the hostname `martin-friese.fritz.box`. Perhaps this got baked into my Fedora installation a little too deep. I guess I should rather have `martin-friese` and let the FRITZ!Box DNS bake in the `.fritz.box` when I am at home.

When I now try to resolve a non-existing hostname, I get this:

```
$ host this-does-not-exist
this-does-not-exist.fritz.box has address 127.0.53.53                                                                  
this-does-not-exist.fritz.box mail is handled by 10 your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.box.
```

An internet search on `your-dns-needs-immediate-attention` tells me that the `.box` TLD is now a valid domain and that therefore there is a clash of my DNS with the global DNS.

The output of `dig` does not really help me.

```
$ dig this-does-not-exist

; <<>> DiG 9.10.4-P5-RedHat-9.10.4-4.P5.fc25 <<>> this-does-not-exist                                                  
;; global options: +cmd                                                                                                
;; Got answer:                                                                                                         
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 10457                                                             
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1                                                

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:                                                                                                  
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096                                                                                  
;; QUESTION SECTION:                                                                                                   
;this-does-not-exist.           IN      A                                                                              

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:                                                                                                  
.                       10800   IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2017013000 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 13 msec                                                                                                 
;; SERVER: 131.220.226.3#53(131.220.226.3)                                                                             
;; WHEN: Mo Jan 30 16:51:54 CET 2017                                                                                   
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 123
```

So I guess I just need to change my hostname to `martin-friese` without the `.fritz.box`? Or should I change it to `friese.martin-ueding.de`, I own the domain but the registrar does not know anything about my laptop.

Comment: Your supposition is my first impression, so you should check it.  Run a `dig` to see which server responds.

Comment: What do you have in `~/.ssh/config`?

Comment: This is likely a DNS issue. Does `host` and/or `dig` always return `127.0.0.1` for non-existing hosts?

Comment: I will have to check that when it happens again. Currently the issue does not happen. Thanks for the `dig` and `host` tips, I'll try them the next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 127.0.53.53 is a safeguard introduced with new gTLDs, call WCIP (Wildcarded Controlled Interruption Program), see https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-collision-2013-12-06-en

And if you look inside https://www.icann.org/sites/default/files/ci-monitoring/citld-complete.csv, you will see that the new `.box` gTLD was in this case between `2016-11-11` and `2017-02-08` for all SLDs under it (wildcard).

In your ssh configuration, the `host` part is whatever token you want, it is purely local. However for the `hostname` you should put there a name that can be resolved on the computer on which the ssh configuration is. The DNS resolution is governed on UNIX system by the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` which will, among other things, specify which nameservers will be queried for recursive queries as well as potential suffixes to add if you use a name with too few dots in it (see `search`, `domain` and `ndots` options).

`friese.martin-ueding.de` does currently successfully resolve to `134.119.45.68` so as long as this resolution stays and hoping it is the correct IP, you should be able to do `ssh friese.martin-ueding.de` from anywhere and be successful on the transport level to establish connection (before speaking about authentication of course).

And by the way, based on whois, `fritz.box` is not an existing domain currently. A lot of "fun" would happen when someone registers it in the future.